# Getting JSON key text with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I Have this kind of JSON Object

```
"{\"date\": \" 9 Marzo\", \"time\": \" 07:00 - 13:20\", \"descrizione\": \" concerto\",   \"alimenti\": [{ \"macchina\":\"si\", \"pollo\":\"no\" }] }";
```

I want to get exactly the string "macchina" and "pollo", which are the keys text/value (I get the Object from an ajax, so "9 Marzo" would be like `response.date`), and same for "si" and "no", I cannot arrive to them.
I have tryed `console.log(response.alimenti[i][0]);` but it's undefined.

i come from the cicle: `for (i = 0; i < response.ruoli.length; i++)`

Comment: did you try to use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: If I parse it, how can I arrive to get "pollo" or "no"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you to the strings "macchina" and "pollo":

```
var json = "{\"date\": \" 9 Marzo\", \"time\": \" 07:00 - 13:20\", \"descrizione\": \" concerto\",   \"alimenti\": [{ \"macchina\":\"si\", \"pollo\":\"no\" }] }";
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
for (var k in obj.alimenti[0]) {
   console.log(k);
}
```

or their values:

```
for (var k in obj.alimenti[0]) {
   console.log(obj.alimenti[0][k]);
}
```

Comment: I think this going to be what I want, I'll make some other tryes

Comment: is there a way to go directly to the value? without the for cycle?

Comment: @Trink You can go directly only if you know the key. For this example: obj.alimenti[0]['macchina'] or obj.alimenti[0].macchina will both get you "si".

Comment: Ok thank, I have changed the JSON structure; but you deserve the upvote cause U only full understood me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `response.alimenti[i][0]` won't work because alimenti is an array of object(s), not an array of arrays.

This instead:

```
var alimenti = response.alimenti[0];
console.log(alimenti.maccina);
console.log(alimenti.pollo);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zcuwfb9s/

Comment: Ok, maybe I have to do a different JSON, because it is supposed that I dont know the name of "alimenti" before getting them, obj.alimenti[0].pollo presume that I know that the JSON contains the property key pollo, Maybe I'm using a bad approach, I should go for {"alimenti" : ["macchina", "pollo"], "alimentiDetail" : ["si", "no"]

Comment: Makes sense. I'd suggest {'alimenti' : [{'name':'macchina', 'value':'si'}, {'name':'pollo', 'value':'no'}]} so you can keep both name+value in one same grouping (object).

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off parsing the JSON object and then extracting the string from the javascript object.

```
i.e var obj = JSON.parse("{\"date\": \" 9 Marzo\", \"time\": \" 07:00 - 13:20\", \"descrizione\": \" concerto\",   \"alimenti\": { \"macchina\":\"si\", \"pollo\":\"no\" } }";);
console.log(obj.alimenti[0].macchina);
```

or pollo

```
console.log(obj.alimenti[0].pollo);
```

Also, that object structure is a little weird. You might want to remove the array from within the alimenti to better access the data.

Comment: I need the array to iterate the datas, because is not supposed I know the name of the key, I litterally want to know the name of the key, so I cannot write .pollo to find "pollo", maybe concept not clear, take referiment to @wojciechpolak answer